# Can someone explain this verb conjugation?

Tags: meaning

This is taken from a songs lyrics

> 罪は忘れさられた

It translates to

The crime was forgotten

So I'd say this is in passive form except what is the さ doing there ?

Shouldn't it be 忘れられた ?

Then why is the さ there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon that is a compound word, not just a conjugation. It is not 忘れる, but [忘{わす}れ去る{さる}](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BF%98%E3%82%8C%E3%81%95%E3%82%8B), meaning "to forget completely".